# How to hide secret key for Azure Bot Service

Tags: azure, web-chat

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#embed-the-web-chat-control-in-your-website), it seems a secret key could be hidden. I tried. The src of the iframe is hidden. But the JavaScript is still could be seen. Is there any way to hide it?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GET request that your linked documentation mentions needs to be done on the server, and only the result should be given to the client. There's no point to doing the whole dance to get a temporary token from the permanent secret if you give the client the permanent secret anyway.